# How to Make Slack Bot Post Notifications in Unique Posts

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, bots

My Python code is below. Basically it makes a connection to a SQL Server database and get a list of notifications to post on a Slack channel. Multiple notifications - if their times are in a close range - sometimes get posted together to the Slack channel as a message.

Currently output is either

```
User John submitted new notification. Link:
```

or

```
User John submitted new notification. Link:
User Jane submitted new notification. Link:
User Max submitted new notification. Link:
```

Python code:

```
import requests
import json
import adodbapi
import adodbapi.ado_consts as adc
import adodbapi.is64bit as is64bit

sqlconn = adodbapi.connect('Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security 
Info=False;Initial Catalog="MyDatabase";Data Source=localhost,1360');
cur = sqlconn.cursor()
cur.execute('''
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
DECLARE @PostedOn datetime
SELECT @PostedOn=LastChecked FROM Notifications
select Email,a.PostedOn, '<https://www.website.com/' +CASE WHEN a.QuestionId IS NOT NULL THEN 
'question' ELSE 'article' END+'/'+CONVERT(varchar,COALESCE(A.questionId,A.ArticleId))+'|Link>'
from UserProfile u
inner join answer a on a.UserId=u.UserId
where exists(select * from Topic et where et.UserId=u.UserId)
AND u.IsExpert=1
AND A.Postedon>@PostedOn

update Notifications
set LastChecked=GETDATE()
''')


sqlconn.commit()
url = 'http://ipaddress:port/bot/chatsecrets/notification-network'
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
hasrows=0
postlist=''
template ='''User {0} submitted new notification. {1}:'''
for row in cur.fetchall():
    postlist = postlist +'\n'+template.format(row[0],row[2])
    hasrows=1

if hasrows:
    response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps({'secret': postlist}), headers=headers)

print (postlist)
```

I would like to configure the code so that bot could send a new message to Slack for each new notification rather than collecting a list of notifications and sending them as a bulk update.

Comment: Hi, so you would like to write on the db and immediately send a notification? you could do a script that waits until the length of the db doesn't change and if it changes, gets the last row and sends a notification

Comment: @matteo-peluso The current script is configured as a scheduled task at Windows Server that runs every 5 mins. Yes, not sure if writing to the database is an ideal approach though.

Comment: My problem is that the current py file prints a single message at the Slack channel if in the last 5 mins only a single post is made. But it prints a list of rows if multiple posts made. I'd like to configure the py file so if multiple rows find in the query then code sends those as multiple bot messages to Slack channel. I am new to python and trying to learn :)